# Why does Excel treat '#N/A and #N/A differently?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not looking for a specific solution in Excel, just trying to understand a few key difference between certain data types.

Imagine this, I have error code `#N/A` in `cell A1`.
I copy and paste this error code in `cell A1` as `Value` (now the red triangle in the top left corner is gone).

I run the following formula in `cell B1`: `=IF(A1="#N/A","Yes","No")`.
This returns an `#N/A error`.

But when I change the value in `cell A1` to `'#N/A`, the formula works correctly; it returns `Yes` in `cell B1`. If I change the value in `Cell A1` to `N/A`, the formula works correctly as well.

`#` is being seen by Excel as `Text`. If for instance I have `#` in `cell A1`, and I ask Excel whether this is text using `=ISTEXT(A1)`, Excel returns a `True` value. If I change the value in `cell A1` to `#N/A`, it is no longer seen as text.

So, my question, why does Excel not treat `'#N/A`, `#N/A`, `N/A`, and `#` the same?

Comment: System generated error code #NA - string version of it '#NA

Comment: `#N/A` is parsed to the value you normally get with the `NA()` function, and tested for with `ISNA()`. Note that this only happens on manual input: `ISNA("#N/A")` is `FALSE`, and `NA() = "#N/A"` is `NA()` because comparing anything to `NA()` is `NA()`.

Comment: You also want to use IFERROR

Comment: So, why does it not treat `#N/A` and `#` as text?

Comment: Because the engineers at Microsoft decided that having `#N/A` parse to the `NA()` value was more intuitive and less surprising than parsing it into a text string, apparently. I don't know what your issue with `#` is, though -- my Excel parses `#` into text, and from your question, apparently so does yours. It's only the exact text `#N/A` that's special.

Comment: Correct, my issue is with `#N/A`. I was hoping there would be a way to treat this as text without adding a `'` in front of it

Answer (score 3):

When the #N/A error code comes up as the result of a formula, Excel is saying "This cell has a not-available type error".  When you enter the value of '#N/A into a cell, Excel is saying "This cell has a text/string value of the characters '#N/A".  What's happening in each cell is not equivalent to Excel.

You probably want to incorporate the IFERROR or ISNA function into your formula.  Right now your code is searching for the later example, the text/string value of '#N/A.  You need to use a function that is looking for an error, not a string of text.

Comment: One oddity is that `=countif(a:a, "#N/A")` returns accurate results.